# Proof of origin of funds in business Account

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, standard-visitor-visas, money, proof-provenance-of-funds

I'm going to apply for a standard visitor visa for my parents. It will be completely sponsored by me, my dad is self-employed and has a sole proprietorship firm. To show their financial situation We are planning to add 6 months of the business statement(current account) for my dad's firm and 6 months personal savings statement. My dad regularly transfers money from the business to a personal savings account and uses that account for day-to-day expenses. His tax returns match the amount shown statements.

1. My question is do we need to show proof of origin of funds in the business(current) account also?
2. Will invoices from my dad's firm reflecting the same amount on the current account work as proof of funds?
3. Do I need to add something else?

P.S: invoices by customers are either paid via cheque (5%), UPI(75%) or cash(20%).

any help with this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As to your question #1: **Yes**, you do need to show proof of provenance of all funds that'll support the trip.

One of the applicant's jobs is to convince the ECO that the funds to be used for the proposed trip were legitimately obtained, whether by the applicant or by the applicant's sponsor(s). Otherwise, the ECO can conclude that the funds were not obtained legally. It's not up to the ECO to prove illegality or impropriety; it's up to the applicant.

As to your question #2: **No**, business invoices alone are far weaker evidence. I would absolutely not rely solely upon them. The reason is that invoices are wholly under the applicant's control, and what's shown on an invoice may be a complete fabrication. The ECO doesn't know if your parents are truth-tellers or liars; the fact that a number is shown on an invoice will not be persuasive.

For a lengthier discussion, see the section "Provenance of Funds" in answer to [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e/92122#92122).

Comment: Thanks, David, I've read the link above and I understand its applicant's job to convince ECO that the funds to be used are legitimately obtained. The funds I'm talking about is customer buying stuff from my father's shop and paying for it either via a bank transaction(80-90% of the time) or via cash(rarely). All the funds go in the current account(business account) and all the invoices are there, what more can we add to prove that the funds are legitimately obtained?

Comment: Also after reading a couple of posts here, Along with a document of income tax return acknowledgment, I'm thinking to attach a balance sheet of my business and profit and loss statement for the year 2021-22 which I used to fill income tax return forms. These are just documents printed on paper by my bookkeeper which we provide during income tax return filing. Do you think that will help?